# WooCommerce hiding shipping information

Tags: woocommerce, information-hiding

Hello I am having trouble setting up the shipping on WooCommerce. I am offering a flat rate shipping but if a customer reaches a certain amount when purchasing they receive free shipping.
But on the checkout page its showing free shipping, flat rate, and Priority mail. How can I hide this.